# How to set the name of a zip file returned from WCF

Tags: vb.net, wcf, zip

I have a WCF written in vb.net that I want to return a zip file from.  Now I can get that working, but I can't figure out how to set the suggested name the file should be saved as (it defaults to the Operation Name with no extension).  When I save the file and then rename it with a .zip extension it is the zip file I expect.

So I'd like to be able to set the file extension, I guess I'm not that bothered by the file name.

Here is my example code:

```
<WebGet(UriTemplate:="Export/", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)>
Public Function ModelVersionExport() As System.IO.Stream

    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"

    'then I call my code that creates the io.stream of the zip file (that works fine)

End Function
```

I thought maybe I could set something on the `OutGoingResponse` but nothing looks right.

Comment: show `creates the io.stream of the zip file`

Comment: the stream does work, my issue is the file it saves is called "Export" with no file extension.

Answer (score 0):

This fixes the issue:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/zip"
```

Should have been fairly obvious but all examples I'd seen used the `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"` setting